# Webpack and babel-loader not resolving `ts` and `tsx` modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm having some trouble when trying to implement Typescript in my project.

- Using Webpack and Babel to transpile and bundle files
- Using `babel-loader` with `@babel/preset-typescript`
- Not using `tsc`

These are my configs.

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const config = {
  // (...) BUNCH OF OTHER CONFIG LINES
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,               // USE THE babel-loader FOR THESE FILE EXTENSIONS
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {

  let presets = [];
  let plugins = [];

  presets = [                                 // NOTE: PRESET ORDER IS LAST TO FIRST
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
        { 
          targets: "> 0.25%, not dead" 
        }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ];

  plugins = [
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components"
  ];

  return ({
    presets,
    plugins,
    // overrides
  });
};
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import firebase from './firebase/firebase';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    firebase={firebase}
  />
  ,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

interface App_PROPS{
  firebase: firebase.app.App | null;
};

const App: React.FC<App_PROPS> = () => {
  return(
    <div>App</div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

**NOTE:** `firebase.ts` is a `.ts` file that exports a `firebase app` object.

When I do `npm start`, I'm getting these errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App'

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './firebase/firebase'
```

This very same config works fine with `JS` files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [babel-loader issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/641) solved my problem.

You've got to add this to your `webpack.config.js` in order to make it resolve `ts` and `tsx` files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
}
```

These "getting started" instructions can be found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter#create-a-webpackconfigjs